# Pop up once every 30 days

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I am totally novice for JS and cookies. I got this code online and tried to change it for 30 days (it was set to 365) but it's probably resetting the cookie for every page and the pop up appears if I go to other page or even return back to the original page. Only things I changed in the code was expire days to 30 and load delay of 30 secs. 
It seems either it's resetting the cookie every time I move to other page or some other problem which I don't understand yet :). I was wondering if there is some more efficient way to have it rather putting the code in every html article page. Something like setting up a cookie in headers or something and recalling using body onload.
Here is the code:

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    <!--
    var expDays = 30; // number of days the cookie should last

    function GetCookie (name) { 
        var arg = name + "="; 
        var alen = arg.length; 
        var clen = document.cookie.length; 
        var i = 0; 
        while (i < clen) { 
            var j = i + alen; 
            if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) 
                return getCookieVal (j); 
            i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1; 
            if (i == 0) break; 
        } 
        return null;
    }

    function SetCookie (name, value,expires) {
        var argv = SetCookie.arguments; 
        var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length; 
        var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null; 
        var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null; 
        var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null; 
        var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false; 
        document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) + 
            ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) + 
            ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) + 
            ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) + 
            ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
    }

    function DeleteCookie (name) { 
        var exp = new Date(); 
        exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 1); 
        var cval = GetCookie (name); 
        document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
    }    
    var exp = new Date(); 
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays*24*60*60*1000));

    function getCookieVal(offset) {
        var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
        if (endstr == -1)
            endstr = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
    }    

    function checkCount() {
        var count = GetCookie('poponce');
        if (count == null) {
            count++;
            SetCookie('poponce', count, exp);

            // Action to take
            dothis()
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function dothis(){
        var windowprops = "left=300,top=240,width=600,height=400,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no";
        window.open("/subscribepopup.html", "", windowprops); // Use to load a page
    }, 30000);
    // -->
</SCRIPT> 

<body OnLoad="checkCount()">
```

Comment: Can it be because I have code on all the html pages rather having it on server (in headers)? As I understand it's checking for cookie in first function and then setting a cookie if it's not found or rewriting cookie if it expired in the next function. Function checkcount is telling it to use function dothis if cookie was not found or expired and dothis function is popping up my desired window after 30 secs due to body onload of checkcount function.

Comment: here is my htaccess...if that's the culprit of conflict.